# Why am I getting a routing error on my ajax-loader.gif?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I've got a JQueryMobile-based Rails app that's working quite well, but I keep seeing the following show up in the logs and I don't know how to get rid of it:

```
No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif")
```

I've actually got my ajax-loader in **/app/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif**, though. Also, I'm pretty sure that the app shouldn't be trying to hit the file since I've got the following JavaScript in the app as well:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function()
  $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

nothing wrong in this, the request to the file is made by following jqm css

```
.ui-icon-loading{background:url("images/ajax-loader.gif");background-size:2.875em 2.875em;}
```

and the absolute path will be relative to your current request of the jqm css path. and hence 404.

And for Loading Widget, from jqm official documentation

```
 It can also be displayed manually for custom loading actions using the $.mobile.loading helper method (See the global method docs).
```

There are two solutions for this.

1. Move the images folder relative to your jqm css folder.
2. Change the background image url in jqm css.

I would recommend first one. This will keep you upgrade friendly.

Comment: As it turns out, after this post and some experimentation, I was able to get rid of the error by creating an assets/images folder and moving it there. Nothing else seemed to work. This put me on the right track, but it wasn't really correct because placing it in vendor/assets didn't actually help (my jqm css is there). I'm still hoping there's a better answer out there.

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite the jQuery mobile CSS by adding the following CSS rule somewhere in your mobile stylesheets.

I added it directly to my mobile manifest file `app/assets/stylesheets/mobile.css.scss`, just below the line `//= require jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css`

```
.ui-icon-loading {
  background: image-url('my-custom-ajax-loader.gif') !important;
}
```

By using the `image-url` helper you get all the benefits of the asset pipeline, such as fingerprinting and CDN utilization.

Comment: This was also helpful to me as it added in the `!important` and the `image-url` pieces I wasn't using previously. Now they've been added to the solution I've cobbled together from the information above and this.